# Using Hugging Face dataset map function to convert a list of paths to PIL images

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I am using the Hugging Face datasets library to load a dataset of image paths. I want to use the map function to apply a transform that opens each image path as a PIL image. However, when I do that, the result is still a path, not an image object. Here is my code:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
from PIL import Image

dataset = load_dataset('eugenesiow/Div2k', 'bicubic_x2',split = 'train[:10]')

def apply_transform(image_path):
    image_path['hr'] = Image.open(image_path['hr'])
    return image_path
dataset = dataset.map(apply_transform)
```

When I check the result, it is:

```
{'bytes': None,
 'path': '/root/.cache/huggingface/datasets/downloads/extracted/6b5de90d5a908c75f5c023a85ea042f9aa961db72fdfba2903372ef258aa0ac5/DIV2K_train_HR/0001.png'}
```

But I want the result to be an image object. It is weird because when I try this form:

```
apply_transform(dataset[0])['hr']
```

I get the right result, which is a PIL image.

How can I fix this problem? Why does the map function not work as expected